# How do I get only the values of the x-axis?

Tags: python, networkx

I have positions of nodes like this:

```
In[1]: pos

Out[2]:
{'A': (5, 0.5),
 'B': (4.8, 0.5),
 'C': (4.6, 0.5)}
```

How do I get only the values of the x-axis? (5, 4.8 and 4.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it.

```
for k,v in pos.items():
   print(pos[k][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have taken a dictionary for points A, B and C. Now you want to see the x-axis values for every point. You read the x-axis value for point A like this: pos['A'][0]

You can print all x-axis values in this way:

```
pos = {'A': (5, 0.5), 'B': (4.8, 0.5), 'C': (4.6, 0.5)}

for i in ['A','B','C']:
    print(pos[i][0],end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `pos` is a dictionary, you can directly access its values as following by just using a single index `[0]` to access the first element.

```
for v in pos.values():
    print (v[0])

5
4.8
4.6
```